# View email previews on lock screen?

Tags: gmail, lock-screens

I am desperately looking for a way to view a preview of a new email message on the lock screen. I would like the screen to light and preview the email for few seconds.

If it is relevant - I have ICS 4.0.4

Comment: It's better to ask for a solution to a problem that you're having than to ask for a recommendation to a solution you've already chosen (in this case, an app). I've edited your question to be a better fit. Please review the [FAQ].

Comment: And after Al edited the question, you are sure to get upvotes :)

Answer (score 2):

Try the widget locker app. It will allow the message preview that scrolls across the notification bar to show. if that isn't enough you could install any widget including mail widgets on the lock screen.